# How to zoom whole activity on multi touch?

Tags: android, android-activity, zooming

### `Problem:`

It's easy to zoom images and web views. But I want to zoom a whole activity. How can I do this?

### `Here, I provide wire-frame:`

[image: Wire-Frame-Of-Activity]

From this you can understand, what I want to do.

### `Request`

If you have any solution of this, then please share.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to apply transformation matrix to root activity view and not to ImgeView?

Comment: What's in the activity you want to zoom? Post your XML.

Comment: Does your activity contain buttons and actions? Or is it just some kind of display?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Yes, My Activity contains TextView,EditText,ImageView and Buttons.

Comment: If you do not need it to be pressable after zooming, you can extract the drawing cache (ScreenShot) and zoom inside the Image. However, views wont receive touches.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I need to scroll the ScrollView and also need to press the buttons. So, now if possible then tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: @Darshak , did you find the solution for the question you have asked, I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 17):

You can simulate zooming in and out by scaling the root activity view. Here's some starter code:

```
View v = findViewById(android.R.id.content); // get reference to root activity view
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    float zoomFactor = 1.5f;
    boolean zoomedOut = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(zoomedOut) { 
            // now zoom in
            v.setScaleX(1);
            v.setScaleY(1);
            zoomedOut = false;
        }
        else {
            v.setScaleX(zoomFactor);
            v.setScaleY(zoomFactor);
            zoomedOut = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Note, the activity will zoom on single clicks as opposed to zooming upon double tap. Also, you probably want to animate the zooming. Look up [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for details how to accomplish this.

[EDIT]
For older API levels, you can use ScaleAnimation. You can also set the duration of the animation. However, a major caveat is that it only modifies the look of the view, but the actual view doesn't change.

```
if(zoomedOut) { // zoom in
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1.5f, 1f, 1.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
    zoomedOut = false;
}
else {
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.5f, 1f, 1.5f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
    zoomedOut = true;
```

Comment: I suppose that is true. One could use ScaleAnimation, which is available for every API level, to achieve zoom. The drawback is that it only modifies where every view is drawn and not the actual View itself.

Comment: @Barney Hsiao

I suppose this code must _work for me._

I will try this code.

**Thank you** in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` to zoom the **complete activity view**.

Then you need to set the pivot point with `setPivotX` and `setPivotY`.

The good examples with details for the whole activity zoom with multitouch:

1) [MultiTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946240/how-to-achieve-multitouch-for-whole-activity) for whole activity.

2) [Zooming](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.in/2011/03/zooming-view-completely.html) view completely.