# how to zoom or scale fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

As everyone knows android built-in-zoom control works for ImageView And WebView. In my project I have 3 fragments that shows in an activity. I need to zoom each fragment by touching or dragging. Is that possible? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806618/how-to-zoom-whole-activity-on-multi-touch) post but it wasn't useful for me. Any idea helps me. 
Thanks.

Comment: i think what you zoom is View,not fragment.

Comment: yes. I should work on view. [this](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/zooming-view-completely.html) helped me. Thanks.