# Android Horizontal Zoom in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, zooming

Hi I have a one LinearLayout that would be contain some other views. I would like to have the ability to zoomIn and zoomOut(ONLY HORIZONTAL ZOOM OUT/IN) on the actual LinearLayout as a whole. Is there a way to do that?

Here am use screen shorts once look at this.

1)`This IS general Image`

[image]

`NOTE:` `Without Effecting remaining viws`

Comment: Here is good answer for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806618/how-to-zoom-whole-activity-on-multi-touch

Answer (score 2):

On touch zoom of View is described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/zoom.html). And if you like zoom on gesture, i think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view) be useful.

Comment: ZoomView is FrameLayout, you can use it instead of LinearLayout: https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view or scale in OnDraw just in this sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view